# Getting 400 Bad request error while uploading file using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm new to angular ,i try to upload file but i got bad request error 
i try all online examples but i get only bad request error.
i display my code below

This my client side part

```
<div ng-controller = "myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>



myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', file);
        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        })
        .success(function(){
        })
        .error(function(){
        });
    }
}]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

    $scope.uploadFile = function(){
        var file = $scope.myFile;
        console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
        var uploadUrl = "/customers/17/artifacts";
        fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
    };

}]);
```

This my server side part

controller part

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/{accountNumber}/artifacts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    void uploadCustomerArtifact(@PathVariable Long accountNumber, @RequestParam("artifact") MultipartFile uploadfile, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.info("RestController UploadFile Called");

        artifactService.uploadArtifacts(accountNumber, uploadfile, request, response);
    }
```

service part

```
@Transactional
    void uploadArtifacts(Long accountNumber, MultipartFile uploadfile, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        BufferedOutputStream stream
        try {

            Validate.assertNotNull(accountNumber,"field.required","Customer account number is mandatory");

            Customer existingCustomer = customerRepository.findByAccountNumber(accountNumber);
            Validate.assertNotNull(existingCustomer, "not.exist", "Customer account number doesn't exist");

            Artifact myArtiFact = new Artifact();
            myArtiFact.name = uploadfile.getOriginalFilename();
            myArtiFact.type = uploadfile.getContentType();
            myArtiFact.content = uploadfile.bytes

            String contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(FilenameUtils.getName(uploadfile.getOriginalFilename()));

            println "contentType : "+contentType

            existingCustomer.addArtifact(myArtiFact);

            customerRepository.save(existingCustomer);
            log.info("UploadArtifacts Success");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            if(stream != null)
            {
                stream.close();
            }
        }       
    }
```

Comment: My guess is that you are not aware to the fact that you need an upload handler at the server-side, you can't just post a file to the folder you want to upload it to, what server-side language do you use?

Comment: What does the server expect? What does actually get sent?

Comment: here is a fiddle of an upload file http://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/yyfatydj/ jsfddle will not allow you to upload files though, it will just show you the progress and a message

Comment: here isi also a useful link http://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/

Comment: i try that link also but i getting that same error @rachel-gallen

Comment: groovy lang @black0ut

Comment: I update my code for your reference,pls kindly check it..

Comment: I don't know groovy at all but two things looks strange to me :
1.why do you set Content-Type to undefined in the js script?
2.why do you expect the request param to be named artifact in @RequestParam("artifact")?